# Android Retrofit - Unable to add response to a List / recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

When I get my response.body() it will not allow me to set it to a List.

SAMPLE GSON:

```
 {
"cod": "200",
"message": 0,
"cnt": 5,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1590861600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 17.74,
            "feels_like": 14.52,
            "temp_min": 15.99,
            "temp_max": 17.74,
            "pressure": 1022,
            "sea_level": 1022,
            "grnd_level": 1021,
            "humidity": 51,
            "temp_kf": 1.75
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 82
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.75,
            "deg": 124
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2020-05-30 18:00:00"
    },
```

Class

```
public class WeatherResponse {

@SerializedName("cod")
@Expose
private String cod;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Long message;
@SerializedName("cnt")
@Expose
private Long cnt;
@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private List<WeatherList> results;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private City city;
```

CODE

```
  private List<WeatherResponse> mWeatherResponseList;


  public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: server response " + response.toString());

            // response code 200 means a successful request
            // if successful store the response body in the log
            if (response.code() == 200) {

              mWeatherResponseList = response.body();   --Throws an error
```

The error states incompatible types: Required Java.util.list - Found WeatherResponse

I did this:

list = new ArrayList(Collections.singleton(((response.body())))); Which appears to have worked. But the problem now is the response has nested Json. Its one object with a list of 5 items. When I try to display the 5 items in the recyclerview it only displays the one object but not the nested list of 5 items which I actually want

Comment: Can you show sample json structure?

Comment: I updated the question with sample json

Comment: post this class data also WeatherResponse

Comment: Which class? Recycler View or Model? The models are huge due to the nature of the json I have the whole thing on Github if that helps

Comment: post this class here WeatherResponse

Comment: Added the class to the question

Comment: Use WeatherResponse instead of List<WeatherResponse>

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Quicklearner Hey mate your answer will onyl give me access to the data in the nested list, there is other information in the response.body that I need. If you check the Json in my question you can see it has two levels.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir It needs to be in list form to be passed to the recyclerview...I think?

Comment: response.body() is not List

Comment: you can use local varibles if you want to use other variables except list

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir hence the problem which is only further complicated by 3 levels of nested json

Comment: I don't understand, you don't need to use list?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir the information has to be used in a recyclerview to display 5 days worth of weather. It has be in a list format to work in the recyclerview

Comment: I have developed this [project](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android) before. You can look if you want.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir it doesnt compile, gradle error but I can see the code on github which is helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: My [WeatherForecast](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/weatherAndroid/Models/WeatherForecast.java) is the same your WeatherResponse

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir in my WeatherResponse I have this 
    private List<WeatherList> results; And then in my WeatherList I have private List<Weather> results; I cannot get any of the values stored in Weather as its nested twice. I don't know how to access the values in there and I need one of them - "description" which describes the weather

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir do you know how I can display a daily forecast for 5 days on the free account?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/weatherAndroid/Adapters/ForecastAdapter.java) is my RecyclerView Adapter.This is how I display the weather for 5 days. ArrayList<WeatherLocation> => List<WeatherList>

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Your code is really helpful mate, do you have any other stuff on github? I feel like I could learn a lot by studying your code

Comment: I have four projects. Two android two iOS. May be they help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
**declare this arraylist like this**

```
private List<WeatherList> mWeatherResponseList=new ArrayList();
```

now in `onResponse()` use this

```
mWeatherResponseList = response.body().getResults();
```

Comment: That will get me access to the inner nested lists, but it will stop me getting necessary information from the outer list

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the entire JSON object but you are required with only the list of results in the JSON object.
so you are getting the single JSON object response in the call, so you could get the list of results this way.

```
private List<WeatherList> mWeatherResponseList;

public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: server response " + response.toString());

        if (response.code() == 200) {

          mWeatherResponseList = response.body().results;
```

This way you are getting the list.

Comment: Theres another list nested in that list. any ideas how I access that?

Comment: there are two ways as i know, you could parse the response again in java like in this blog post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java. or you can probably change the type of the variable to whatever type is like i changed the WeatherList. and then use response.body().results.getWeather and getClouds for individual result